# I am trying to change the text color but for some reason it is not working

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to change the color of the text of my p tag but for some reason it is not working. I am very new to coding so any advice would help.

```
import React from 'react'
import { SocialIcon } from 'react-social-icons';


type Props = {}

export default function Header({}: Props) {
  return (
    <header className="sticky top-0 flex items-start justify-between max-w-7xl mx-auto z-20 xl:items-center">
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
            {/* Social Icons */}
            <SocialIcon 
                url="https://" 
                fgColor="gray" 
                bgColor="transparent"
            />
            <SocialIcon 
                url="https://" 
                fgColor="gray" 
                bgColor="transparent"
            />
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer">
            <SocialIcon 
                className="cursor-pointer"
                network="email" 
                fgColor="gray" 
                bgColor="transparent"
            />
            <p className="text-gray-400">Why wont this work</p>
        </div>
    </header>
  );
}

**tailwind.config.js**

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./compnents/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

the line of code Why wont this work

does not do anything and simply leaves the text black

I honestly have no idea what to do here. I thought the other div classNames might be affecting the p tag somehow so I tried deleting them but that didn't work either. Below I attached an image of it as proof.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao1L2.png)

Comment: it looks like you forgot to include project files in tailwind.config.js. can you please share what it looks like in your case?

Comment: oh my bad. Here it is

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./compnents/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: @YaningWang It would be better if you update your question with `tailwind.config.js`, that's better than posting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your tailwind.confing.js is not correct or something wrong.
Tailwind Css supplies the public document.
please check here.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors

For example, can you set your customize color on  `theme.extend.colors` in  tailwind.config.js ?

you can customize for what you expect.

Here is sample.

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        gray: {
          400: '#303030', // custom
        },
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Please rebuild your app after changing that config at last.
try it.